# route flask from scheduled function

Tags: python, flask, routes

I have a Flask app, which is running a web-app to control an alarm. I use apscheduler to trigger a function `triggerAlarm()` and within that I want to have the logic to actually trigger it, but also I want to have the web-page to display another alarm.html, no matter which site the user is currently on.

The idea is to show the user, that the alarm went off by opening another html page (possibly the main page, which has context dependent text and layout)! Also the page content is outdated after an alarm. The client must reload the page, if the after-alarm info should be displayed/updated.

This is the key problem: in my head it is necessary to redirect every client to the alarm page at this event. Maybe there is a better solution all along. (I don't want to use JavaScript, since I use 4 languages already besides the 3 I use regularly.)

The problem is, that the function itself has no "route" and is not part of the app (this is what I think happens). Also I cannot easily make it a route, since it is activated not by a html request, but by the scheduler.
How can I trigger a function and redirect to a specified page?

*I tried `redirect()` and `RequestRedirect()` w/ and w/o `url_for()` and     `return render_template('index.html', **templateData)` ... but I cannot load the desired page.

The code looks something like this:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
# Web Server Gateway WSGI
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.start()
scheduler.add_job(triggerAlarm,'date',run_date=somedate)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    # prepare templateData
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)

def triggerAlarm():
    # this doesn't work, since it is called by the scheduler and has no route!
    return redirect(url_for("/"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined a method, "triggerAlarm()", and want to make it available to a route, then create your route like:

```
@app.route("/alarm-url")
def web_alarm():
    triggerAlarm()
    return redirect(url_for("/"))
```

This will cause the same thing that happens when the scheduler runs triggerAlarm() to happen when a user hits the route /alarm-url, and then return them home.

The takeaway is that you can define methods outside of flask route, in other modules, etc, and then call those methods in a flask route.

***Update***

If you have to keep triggerAlarm() separate from any routes you could do something like:

```
class StatusDenied(Exception):
  pass

@app.errorhandler(StatusDenied)
def web_alarm(error):
  return redirect(url_for("/")) 

def triggerAlarm():
  ...
  raise StatusDenied
```

Comment: This is the opposite problem I am asking for. I am trying to call web_alarm() FROM triggerAlarm(), not the other way around.  In your case the user requests a route and after that the triggerAlarm() is called. I want the scheduled function triggerAlarm() to automatically redirect the user to the route web_alarm(). Hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: @mike There may be some confusion here.  If triggerAlarm() is scheduled rather than attached to a route, who is getting redirected?  How did the user first enter a context where triggerAlarm() would redirect them?  Do you intend for triggerAlarm() to redirect someone a certain amount of time after entering a specific view, like a trial for an online application that redirects to the homepage once the trial is up?

Comment: @mike You could have triggerAlarm() raise an exception and then `@app.errorhandler(raised error)` as the 'route' for web_alarm? See if my edit helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that! I tried to rewrite the question to clear that up! Basically I wanted to redirect everyone from all pages to the alarm page at the alarm event. Mybe this is my big mistake that this makes no sense an i need to modify my other pages to deal with that.

Comment: I mark this as solution until I am sure what exactly was the key point that I wanted this. I think your question leads to the obvious solution: if the alarm is triggered, a variable =True. If this variable is set, all Other routes redirect to the alarm route! This way all users are caught - only the update problem persists, that a user could sit on old info..